# MVC and fail AJAX call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes

I have a controller method:

```
    public async Task SaveRouting(string points, int tripId, decimal totalMileage)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            //....
            await _serviceTrip.UpdateTotalMileageAsync(tripId, totalMileage);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Only ajax calls are allowed");
    }
```

so, as we can see, this method returns Task, so nothing to client. But if something wrong (i.e. totalMileage is less or equal 0) I want to return 422 status code and dictionary with invalid data, like:
{ "totalMileage" : "Total mileage should be greater than 0" }

How to do it? 
I try to do it:

```
            if (totalMileage <= 0)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 422; // 422 Unprocessable Entity Explained
            }
```

but how to describe an error?

Comment: why not returning `Task<HttpStatusCodeResult>` ?

Comment: @derloopkat how to describe errors in this case?

Comment: your task has no return statement, and anyway it should be returning some sort of response object or data, not just Task - you can't serialise a Task to JSON. Lots of tutorials and example online which would give you sample code to structure it correctly.

Comment: @OlegSh, one option is returning http error and add details as response headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to describe the error after setting `Response.StatusCode`, then you have to write into the body of the http response by calling `Response.Body.Write(byte[],int, int)`. 
Therefore, you can convert your *response message* to a byte array using the following method:

```
public byte[] ConvertStringToArray(string s)
{
    return new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(s);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
byte[] bytes = ConvertStringToArray("Total mileage should be greater than 0");
Response.StatusCode = 422;
Response.Body.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
```

But you can further simplify this using extension methods on `ControllerBase`